# Adding a new column from table to mysql query

Tags: mysql

I used for a while Stack, you help me a lot ... this is my first question, I hope to be able to expose correctly.

I need to retrieve all value from a table and add one column with sum value from another table.
This what I mean:

q1=>

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE role >30 AND role <50 AND available = 1 AND active = 1
```

to q1 add a new column from q2=>

```
SELECT SUM(budget) AS totalBudget FROM projects_assignments
```

- Relation between tables are idUser
- more over in projects_assignments I have some users of users' table and some user is in projects_assignments only one time.

**example:**

table1 = `idUser`, some values

table2 = `idUser`, `budget`, other es: values (1,10000,40),(1,5000,30),(2,5000,30)

My expected result is:

```
idUser,table1column1,table1column2,totalBudget

1,x,y,15000(10k+5k)

2,x,x,5000

3,x,y,0

...

n,x,y,0
```

Thanks a lot,
Matteo

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.column1,
table1.column2,
table1.column3,
sum(table2.budget) as totalBudget
from table1
inner join table2
on table1.idUser = table2.idUser
where...
group by table1.idUser
```

Comment: You are making gross assumptions about the structure of these tables.